# onNavigationItemSelected is not getting called

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am beginner in Android. I have created Navigation Drawer Activity using the default template for Navigation Drawer Activity project. It is working properly. Now i need to change the drawer menu list and add new items. I have added one item in activity_main_drawer.xml as follows, its showing properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_others"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        android:title="Others" />
   </group>
</menu>
```

Though the sample application is running and Fragments are opening on menu item click. but there is no onNavigationItemSelected (as i found in different documents). I am unable to get how they(fragments) are being called.

The default code of Main Activity is as follows:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements 
       NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.


        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,R.id.nav_others)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);//.
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

I have added onNavigationItemSelected as below but its also not working.

```
    @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_others) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your MainActivity after finding your view:

```
navigationView.setNavigationOnItemSelected(this)
```

Comment: Thank you first of all. Yes I have inserted the code but then also its not working.

Comment: @Santanu You are using the Android Navigation Component which overrides the whole functionality.